# JavaScript Descriptors: enumerable/configurable/writable are not true by default?

Tags: javascript, descriptor

I was reading one of John Resig's blogs on [new ES5 features](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/), one being `Object` descriptors. Earlier in his blog, John writes:

> The three attributes (writable, enumerable, and configurable) are all
>   optional and all default to true. Thus, the only property that you’ll
>   need to provide will be, either, value or get and set.

Later on he provides an example:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty( obj, "propertyname", {
    value: true,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});

(function() {
    var name = "John";

    Object.defineProperty( obj, "name", {
        get: function(){ return name; },
        set: function(value){ name = value; }
    });
})();
```

However, when checking the property descriptor for `name`, it is not configurable or enumerable and consequently I am unable to access it in a for loop.

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'name'))
> Object {enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

Shouldn't `name` be both enumerable and configurable? What am I missing here?

Comment: the default is actually `false` when using `Object.defineProperty`, it's `true` for "normal" props created by literals/assignment. i think this simplifies coding the usual defaults for such dynamic props. look at `var obj = {}; Object.defineProperty( obj, "propertyname", { value: true});Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'propertyname');` for a sanity check.

Comment: The blog is mistaken. The default is `false` when using `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: @dandavis Are you saying: if you assign a property's value in its descriptor, then other properties will automatically be set to true?

Comment: Just tested the above--other properties still false. Regardless, you're both correct: Unless explicitly defined in the descriptor, enumerable/configurable/writable will be false and value will be undefined.

Comment: That reference you cite must be at least five years old, and may have been written at a point in time when the spec was still fluid.

Comment: @torazaburo that can definitely be the case. Regardless, I've emailed the author regarding possible discrepancy and will update my answer if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The default values for descriptor properties is false or undefined.

The blog has an error. Unless explicitly defined in the descriptor, `enumerable`/`configurable`/`writable` will be `false` and `value` will be `undefined`. Accessor descriptor properties will default to `undefined` as well.

This is concurrent with the MDN [notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> Both data and accessor descriptors are objects. They share the following  required keys:
>
> **configurable**
>
> true if and only if the type of this property descriptor
> may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the
> corresponding object. Defaults to false.
>
> **enumerable**
>
> true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the  properties on the corresponding object. Defaults to false.
>
> A data descriptor also has the following optional keys:
>
> **value**
>
> The value associated with the property. Can be any valid
> JavaScript value (number, object, function, etc). Defaults to
> undefined.
>
> **writable**
>
> true if and only if the value associated with the
> property may be changed with an assignment operator. Defaults to
> false.
>
> An accessor descriptor also has the following optional keys:
>
> **get**
>
> A function which serves as a getter for the property, or undefined
> if there is no getter. The function return will be used as the value
> of property. Defaults to undefined.
>
> **set**
>
> A function which serves as a
> setter for the property, or undefined if there is no setter. The
> function will receive as only argument the new value being assigned to
> the property. Defaults to undefined.

Answer (score 5):

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#table-4), data properties are non-configurable, non-enumerable and non-writable by default.

> If the initial values of a property's attributes are not explicitly
>   specified by this specification, the default value defined in [Table
>   4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#table-4) is used.
>
> Table 4: Default Attribute Values
>
> ```
> ┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┐
> │  Attribute Name  │  Default Value  │
> ├──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
> │ [[Value]]        │ undefined       │
> │ [[Get]]          │ undefined       │
> │ [[Set]]          │ undefined       │
> │ [[Writable]]     │ false           │
> │ [[Enumerable]]   │ false           │
> │ [[Configurable]] │ false           │
> └──────────────────┴─────────────────┘
> ```

However, when you create a data property via an assignment, then [CreateDataProperty](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-createdataproperty) defines it as configurable, enumerable and writable.

> Let *newDesc* be the PropertyDescriptor{[[Value]]: *V*, [[Writable]]:
>   true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true}.